# Xcode 7.1 iOS Simulators looks weird

Tags: ios, xcode7

[image]

After updated Xcode to 7.1
iOS Simulator looks weird as the picture.

Does anyone had the same problem like this?
I can't specify which version of iOS when debugging via the simulator.

Comment: They almost look like device ids (UDID), yet, there are not enough characters. Do you have multiple simulator versions loaded... 7.1, 8.1, 9.1? The only one that is singular is the iPad Pro, which is new, so, it wouldn't run the other versions of iOS.

Comment: Agree with @MarcWatson.

Comment: Before this I had Xcode 6.x with have 7.x.
I try to uninstall already but doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating xcode 7.1 looking same but you can know which vesion IOS when debugging  after running app in simulator ..
[image]

Comment: This quite a bit tricky since we should know the iOS version
before running the simulator.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Just go to the path:`~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices`

[image: Pic]

2. and delete all devices in this folder

[image: Pic]

3. Open the Xcode and go to the `Devices`, add your Simulator.

[image: Pic]

Answer (score 1):

```
You have to Manage it from
```

> **Window > Device** >

[image]

**Delete all Simulator and Create New Simulator as per requirement**

[image]